# when the static variables will be initialized

Tags: java, static-members

Might be a silly question, but when is the static variable initialized(so it occupies memory) while the program is running?

```
public class TestStaicInitilization {
    int i;
    public static final TestStaicInitilization test = new TestStaicInitilization();
    TestStaicInitilization(){
        this.i = 10;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(TestStaicInitilization.test.i);
    }
}
```

the output is: `10`

Is the `TestStaicInitilization.test` initialized while loading the class itself or when it is first accessed?

Comment: In the example you give, those two things are the same. The class is loaded when it is first accessed, and static initializers are run when the class is loaded.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I believe Java lazy-loads classes (ie. doesn't load them from file until code needed from them is invoked). After that point, the static initializers are run. I think someone more familiar with the JLS can answer that better, though.

Comment: Actually, class initialization is lazy too.  See the linked Q&A.

Comment: @dcsohl the static initializers also initialize static member variables?

Comment: Yes, a static initializer is either a) an assignment of a `static` field, or b) a `static { ... }` code block in the class. So: the expression `TestStaicInitilization` is evaluated left-to-right, as is the norm. When you first refer to `TestStaicInitilization`, the JVM loads the class, which triggers the static initializers--at this point, `test` is created and assigned. So now you have `TestStaicInitilization.test` and can look at its `i`.